# Problem with mysqldump and view

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, view

When using `mysqldump` to backup MySQL, I got following error.

```
mysqldump --all-databases --routines >> all.sql
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show table status like 'hdkien'': SELECT command denied to user 'tungbt'@'192.168.12.197' for column 'id' in table 'hdcn_hd' (1143)
```

`hdkien` is a view

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`tungbt`@`192.168.12.197` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `hdcn`.`hdkien` AS (...striped...)
```

User `tungbt`@`192.168.12.197` has already had the privilege to select on table `hdcn_hd` and I can select from view `hdkien` without problem.

```
mysql> select * from hdkien limit 1;
+------+-----------+
| id   | shd       |
+------+-----------+
|  876 | ADFADFA1  |
+------+-----------+
```

More info:

- MySQL version: `mysql-community-server-5.5.37-4.el6.x86_64`
- OS: CentOS 6.5

Why I got the error when running `mysqldump` and how can I resolve it?

**Update 1 (2014/04/17)**

I run `mysqldump` with user `'root'@'localhost'`.

```
mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...striped...' WITH GRANT OPTION                             |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The user `'tungbt'@'192.168.12.197'` is the definer of view `hdcn.hdkien` (and the `SQL SECURITY` is `DEFINER`.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for tungbt@192.168.12.197                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'tungbt'@'192.168.12.197' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...striped...'                             |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hdcn`.* TO 'tungbt'@'192.168.12.197'                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Update 2**

```
$ mysql -ANe"SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER()"
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
```

**Update 3**

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(1) MySQLGrantsCount,VERSION() MySQLVersion FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';
+------------------+--------------+
| MySQLGrantsCount | MySQLVersion |
+------------------+--------------+
|               42 | 5.5.37-log   |
+------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Does `tungbt`@`192.168.12.197` still exist?

Comment: @dwjv yes, for sure.

Comment: I was able to dump my views after I changed their 'definer' to the current user, "dev@%" (with suitable privileges, of course).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have the [SHOW VIEW privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-view). I wrote about this Dec 2013 : [Which are the minimum privileges required to get a backup of a MySQL database schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55546/which-are-the-minimum-privileges-required-to-get-a-backup-of-a-mysql-database-sc/55572#55572)

In that post I show these minimum privileges for a mysqldump

- [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_select)
- [SHOW VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-view) (If any database has Views)
- [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger) (If any table has one or more triggers)
- [LOCK TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_lock-tables) (If you use an explicit `--lock-tables`)

You should run this command:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR tungbt@192.168.12.197;
```

If `SHOW VIEW` is not there, that's the reason why.

## UPDATE 2014-04-16 23:06 EDT

When you did this

```
mysqldump --all-databases --routines >> all.sql
```

I see you did not specify the user and password. That being the case, you were not logged in as `root@localhost`. You will have to be explicit in specifying the root user

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases --routines >> all.sql
```

You will see the password prompt. Enter the root@localhost password and you are off and running.

You could also specify the password too

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --all-databases --routines >> all.sql
```

## Give it a Try !!!

## WILD SUGGESTIONS

If you are using `.~/my.cnf` and still getting an error, you might be hitting this situation in [Bug #70907 mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show table status': SELECT command denied to user '](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70907)

If the config file is `.~/my.cnf` is really `/root/.my.cnf`, perhaps you are not logged in as Linux root. You may have to run sudo.

Please run this command

```
mysql -ANe"SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER()"
```

If you do not see `root@localhost` twice, then you are not authenticating correctly.

In `.my.cnf` you need to make sure that user and password are under the `[client]` section

```
[client]
user=root
password=rootpassword
```

not under the `[mysql]` section.

## UPDATE 2014-04-17 13:53 EDT

I cannot help look at that bug report and wonder the following: Since you have DEFINER=`tungbt`@`192.168.12.197`, it is possible that root@localhost is behaving like `tungbt`@`192.168.12.197` ? I say this because according to the [**MySQL Documentation on CREATE VIEW**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html): `At view definition time, the view creator must have the privileges needed to use the top-level objects accessed by the view. For example, if the view definition refers to table columns, the creator must have some privilege for each column in the select list of the definition, and the SELECT privilege for each column used elsewhere in the definition.`

You could change the definer of the view to root@localhost and try the mysqldump again

Comment: See my update. The user `root@localhost` and `tungbt@192.168.12.197` both have had the `SHOW VIEW` privilege already.

Comment: That's not the case. I specify my username and password in `~/.my.cnf`. I try with `-u` and `-p` for `mysqldump` as you said above and have the same error.

Comment: Added wild suggestions to help you look closer.

Comment: See my update. I surely run `mysqldump` with `root@localhost`. I have the same problem as the reporter in [bug:70907](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70907). I have upgraded MySQL from 5.1 to 5.5 one month ago. How to know if I have run `mysql_upgrade` properly or not?

Comment: Ouch, you ran mysql_upgrade. Please run this query `SELECT COUNT(1) MySQLGrantsCount,VERSION() MySQLVersion FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';` What number and version does it output ???

Comment: see the output on my new update.

Comment: Silly me. 

I found out the real problem. 

Somehow, I have a clone of db `hdcn` (name `hdcn_old`). And the problem is user `tungbt@192.16.12.179` do not have the correct privileges on this db. The error line (as I post above) do not have the db name, so I assume the error occur when dumping `hdcn` db.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with not being able to do a mysqldump on my view as root:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `v_view01`': View 'my_db.v_view01' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)
```

In my case, it was because my underlying schema changed, so the view that relied on it was no longer valid.  Even though, I was executing the dump as root, it still says "or invoker of view lacks rights...".  The solution was simple:

```
drop view v_view01
```

Since the view was already outdated, I just dropped it, then the mysqldump proceeded like normal.

Answer (score 3):

Mine couldn't show create view on a view that didn't exist - so job just quit.  So I did these two things:

```
create or replace view v_view01 as select * from any_table;
drop view v_view01;
```

Bigger problem is `mysqldump` defaults to stop on an error - horrible idea!!!

If you need all other good tables backed up then add option   `--force` and options like these...

```
mysqldump -u root -p${MP} --all-databases --lock-tables --debug-info --comments --dump-date --force --events --routines --add-drop-table --add-locks --log-error=/somewhere/mysqldump.err >all_db.`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M"`.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue is that my view was corrupted/broken as one of the object (table) it used didn't exist anymore.

The solution was to drop the view and recreate it with the correct SQL syntax.